# Como guardar datos de variables en cache NodeJs

Tags: javascript, nodejs

tengo un sistema en el cual ingresan muchos usuarios , a través de una API obtengo datos de indicadores financieros y los paso a  variables , mi consulta es que hay alguna manera de que esos datos se me guarden en la Cache del servidor una vez al dia , así mis usuarios no tendrán que realizar siempre llamadas a esa API solo una vez al día .

**SINTAXIS QUE LLAMA A MIS INDICADORES FINANCIEROS DIARIOS**

```
    function obtenerIND() {

    $.getJSON('https://mindicador.cl/api', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        var dailyIndicators = data;
        UF = dailyIndicators.uf.valor;
        EURO = dailyIndicators.euro.valor;
        DOLAR = dailyIndicators.dolar.valor
        UTM = dailyIndicators.utm.valor
        $("#UF").html(UF);
        $("#EURO").html(EURO);
        $("#DOLAR").html(DOLAR);
        $("#UTM").html(UTM);

    }).fail(function() {
        console.log('Error al consumir la API!');
    });
}
```

Este es el codigo que llama a mis datos y quisiera que se almacenaran en la cache del servidor , como se puede realizar eso en NodeJs

Comment: Si lo que quieres es evitar llamadas desde el navegador, es éste el que tendrá que guardar los datos. Por tanto el uso de NodeJs u otra tecnología en el lado del servidor es irrelevante. Te consejo mirar el API de WebStorage (propiedad `localStorage`)

Comment: @PabloLozano, lo que me parece que el O.P. plantea es evitar que su Servidor realice una petición a dicha `API` (externa a él) por cada solicitud de usuario que tenga. Es decir, el O.P. desea persistir la data de la API externa, diariamente en su propio servidor para que desde ese repositorio puedan consumirla sus usuarios. @Daniela, yo te recomendaría que le dieras un vistazo a [node-persist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-persist). Yo mismo he implementado alguna vez con esta librería y es realmente fácil de usar y la puedes programar para que actualice la data en el intervalo elegido.

Comment: @MauricioContreras Es posible, lo que pasa es que ver jQuery me ha hecho pensar más en navegadores que en NodeJS... pero ante la duda he comentado en lugar de poner una posible respuesta. Daniela, ¿podrías aclarar este punto? La pregunta sería interesante en ambos casos

Comment: Gracias, persist-cache me sirvio para lo que queria , funciona de igual manera que node-persist :)